# Using ffmpeg to add height (as black bars) to video file without quality loss

Tags: ffmpeg, encoding, compression, lossless

I have a file of resolution 3840x1632, but my TV stretches the picture vertically to fill up all 2160 pixels of height.  Is it possible to use ffmpeg to add blank / black height, while preserving the video and audio quality?

Tried doing this, which seemed to work (took about 2 hours, the same length of the video), but greatly reduced the file size/video quality):

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -filter:v "pad=3840:2160:0:280" -c:a copy my_output_video.mkv
```

Is there a switch to say "keep everything else the same"?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to manually set encoding parameters.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -filter:v "pad=3840:2160:0:280,setsar=1" -crf 18 -preset faster -c:a copy my_output_video.mkv
```

The CRF option sets the tradeoff for size/quality. Lower values produce better quality but larger files. The preset will increase speed, but for same quality, the file size will be larger.

The setsar filter has been added as a precaution in case your player reads the SAR stored in the file and stretches the video based on that value.

Answer (score 1):

You can do transformations with `-c:v libx264 -crf 0` X264 has lossless mode, which it enters with `-crf 0`. They implemented real lossless video encoding, this is not widely known - but it works perfectly.

I use it all the time.

Be ready - it takes GBs - especially for videos of real-life (not graphics etc...)

Doing screen recording for programs and graphis in `-crf 0` - is perfect - it compresses them really great and uses relatively small CPU power.

You also can control compression complexity it uses, with the presets (`fast`, `veryslow` ... etc). And you also can recomress lossles into more compressed lossless.

Everything for lossless is the same as for all x264's, except that it is the real lossless.

Comment: The OP intends to play the files on a TV, and most h/w or s/w decoders don't support Hi444 profile which is what `crf/qp 0` requires.

Comment: @Gyan Yep, what you say is true. Except I said "transformations". The idea I represent - person does not know how to play with lossless processing. He can develop workflow in lossless form in stages, and then all that can be moved into on-the-fly bulk processing into lossy.
Also lossless can be directly compared. Like I had two days before. If input file has 11.8 GB, letterboxed file also would be 11.8 GB - you see right away that all information is preserved.
& Lossless can always be encoded into lossy.

Answer (score 0):

###### Here is my solution with explanation

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -filter:v "pad=3840:2160:0:280,setsar=1" -c:a copy -c:v libx265 -x265-params lossless=1 my_output_video.mkv
----------111111111----------------2222-3333-4-555----------------------------------------------------------6666666666666666666

Legend
1 - input filename
2 - Target X dimension
3 - Target Y
4 - Bar's target X pos. Best: Floor( (Target X - Current X) / 2) . If the value is 0, no vertical baps will be present.
5 - Bar's target Y pos. Best: Floor( (Target Y - Current Y) / 2) . If the value is 0, no horizontal baps will be present.
6 - output filename

Notes
-c:a copy is to maintain lossless-ness
-x265-params lossless=1 option is for lossless encoding. Adding -crf 0 is not required.
-c:v libx265 - added to reduce output video quality while maintaining lossless-ness
Floor() - means to floor DOWN where applicable (ideally, no non-integer calculations occur)
```

My example command to add bars from 1660x780 to 1920x1080,

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter:v "pad=1920:1080:130:150,setsar=1" -crf 0 -c:v libx265 -x265-params lossless=1 my_output_video.mp4
```

###### Sources,

- https://video.stackexchange.com/a/24756
- https://video.stackexchange.com/a/28659
- http://underpop.online.fr/f/ffmpeg/help/pad.htm.gz
- https://superuser.com/a/1667833
- https://forum.videohelp.com/threads/382367-X265-Lossless-not-really-lossless-and-I-can-prove-it
- https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.265